# Display QRadioButton as QPushButton like c#

Tags: c++, qt, qradiobutton

In c# I can apply this property on RadioButton

[image]

So the RadioButton is displayed like a PushButton but it's still a radio button.

Is there a way to do that with Qt in c++ ? maybe programmaticaly.

Comment: What behaviour do you need that you can't get from just using QPushButton?

Comment: Is there a way to select juste one QPushButton in a group like for QRadioButton in Layout ? or should i do programmatically ?

Comment: Are you using Qt Designer?

Comment: Yes QTCreator. I accept your answer i did it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QPushButton` and `setCheckable( true )`.  This will get you the same behaviour as a `QRadioButton`.

Comment: Well, not exactly same behavior... Other buttons must be unchecked automatically

Comment: Supplement: You also have to set autoExclusive = True

Comment: @g2m.agent it is working perfectly. Thnks